# How can I improve Loki line_format output to include an embedded html link?

Tags: squid, grafana-loki, logql

I'm using Grafana loki to monitor squid proxy logs and then I run the following query on them to determine the exact youtube URL visited.  (In order for this to work, I've installed a man in the middle certificate.)

```
{job="squid",url_domain="youtube.com"} | regexp "(?P<datetime>\\d+.\\d+)\\s+(?P<loadtime_ms>\\d+)\\s(?P<source>\\d+.\\d+.\\d+.\\d+)\\s(?P<action>\\w+)\\/(?P<html_code>\\d+)\\s(?P<bytes>\\d+)\\s(?P<method>\\w+)(\\S+)(?P<search_header>.+)video_id=(?P<video_id>[\\w|\\d|-]+)" | line_format "{{.source}} https://www.youtube.com/watch/{{.video_id}}"
```

How could I further improve this by

1. embedding a link into the output making the https://www.youtube.com/watch/XXX clickable?
2. How might I be to call an external process to get the HTML title page, similar to this python post processing script on the squid log itself

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import requests
from datetime import datetime
import time

access_file = open('/var/log/squid/access.log','r')
file_content = access_file.readlines()

timestamp = time.time()
filename = "/var/www/html/squid-reports/youtube/" + "youtube-" + str(timestamp) + ".html"

file = open(filename,"a")
file.write("<html><head><title>Youtube activity for %s</title></head><body>" % (datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
file.write("<h1>Youtube activity for %s</h1>" % (datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
file.write("<table><tr><th>Youtube Site</th><th>Ip Address</th></tr>")
line_count = 0
for line in file_content:
    data = line.split()
    ip_address = data[2]

    timestamp = data[0]
    data = timestamp.split(".")
    timestamp = int(data[0])

    if ("GET https://www.youtube.com/" in line) and ("ptracking" in line) and ("adhost" not in line):
        data = line.split("&")
        for item in data:
            if "video_id" in item:
                data = item.split("=")
                video_id = data[1]
                video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch/" + video_id

                response = requests.get(video_url)

                output = response.text
                output = output.lower()

                video_label = ""
                step1 = output.split("<title>")
                step2 = step1[1].split("</title>")
                video_label = step2[0]

                if len(video_label) == 0:
                    video_label = "Unable to retrieve video label"
                newline = "<tr><td><a href=\"%s\" target=_blank\">%s</a></td><td>%s</td></tr>" % (video_url, video_label, ip_address)
                file.write(newline)
    line_count += 1

file.write("</table></body></html>")
file.close()
```

Thanks in advance!